# А как прописать флаги в open()?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, arm, gnu

Ну, собственно, имеется код `GNU assembler aarch64`:

```
.data

filename:
    .ascii "file.asm"

.text
globl _start
_start:
    ; int open(const char* path, int flags)
    ldr x0, =filename ; filename
    mov x1, ???       ; FLAG
    mov w8, #180      ; open() syscall
    svc #0
```

И вот проблема. Я не могу написать так:

```
mov x1, O_CREAT
mov x1, #O_CREAT
```

Мне бы число этого аргумента: по идее, именно его надо туда писать. Да только где взять числа к флагам `int flags`??? `man 2 open` тоже молчит.

Comment: эм, это таблица системных вызовов. С этим у меня нет проблем, у меня беда с аргументом, который надо передать в `open()`

Comment: Открыть `fcntl.h`  и посмотреть, чему равен интересующий флаг?

Comment: не помогло, не нашёл.

Comment: `printf("%d", (int)O_CREAT)`?

Comment: wololo, там число не то, что я в fcntl-ах нашёл.

Comment: 1) `0100 == 0x40 == 64`. 2) `не помогло, не нашёл` ... `там число не то, что я в fcntl-ах нашёл` ???

Comment: а, понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я сделал вот что (опишу командами):

```
 ~ $ nano write.cpp
```

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream filesys;
    filesys.open("file.asm", ios::app);
    filesys.close();
    return 0;
}
```

```
 ~ $ g++ write.cpp
 ~ $ sudo strace ./a.out | grep open
# сокращу вывод
openat(AT_FDCWD, "file.asm", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND, 0666);
```

Что же, используется-таки `openat()`. Ищу столь бесящий **AT_FDCWD**: первый же запрос в гугл дал ответ). А дальше через `fcntl.h` нашёл ответ:

```
.data

file:
    .ascii "file.asm"

.text

.globl _start

_start:
    mov x0, -100  ; AT_FDCWD
    ldr x1, =file ; const char* filename
    mov x2, 0100  ; O_CREAT
    mov x3, 0700  ; int mode
    mov w8, #56   ; openat()
    svc #0

    mov x0, #0    ; return 0
    mov w8, #93
    svc #0
```